# Question using $f(A) =\mathcal Sf(\lambda)\mathcal S^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given

$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\\-2&3}$$

I found $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$

$$\mathcal S=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&2}$$

$$\mathcal S^{-1}=\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&1}$$

Using the formula $\mathcal S\Lambda\mathcal S^{-1}$

Calculate:

a) $(A-I)^{4000}$

b) $e^{2A}$

c) $(3A-5I)(I+4A-4A^2+A^3)^{-1}$

For part a) and c), I am having difficulty with the $(A-I)$ calculation when I replace $A$ with the eigenvalues and insert them into the $\Lambda$ matrix.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Enclose formulas in dollar signs, like `$e^2A$` or `$f(A)=\mathcal Sf(\lambda)\mathcal S^-1$`. Also: put a blank between `\mathcal` and `S`:  `\mathcal S`

Comment: @Martin~I tried to use the math formatting and it didn't work.  What am I missing other than the spaces, etc. that you suggested?

Comment: Okay, I did it for you. You can see what I did by clicking the [edit] link. One thing I overlooked: for superscripts you need to enclose multiple letters in braces like `A^{-1}` and `(A-I)^{4000}` (and +1 for showing your work!)

Comment: @Martin~Thanks!  Do I need to highlight or something in order for everything to work?  Or just type away?

Comment: You just type away, no need to highlight anything. Below the field in which you type your question there should be a preview of the rendered output, so you can check whether the formulas are rendered the way you want them to be.

Comment: @Martin~Thanks again! I did see that you put $$ everywhere.  So now I know how that works.  :)

Comment: Maybe you didn't see [this summary of the essentials](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/49437) on which you can find more or less everything you'll need in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the question title, the idea is that when $A = S \Lambda S^{-1}$ is the diagonalization, then $f(A) = S f(\Lambda) S^{-1}$ holds for sufficiently nice $f$ (in particular, those $f$ that are analytic in a domain containing the eigenvalues of $A$).

So for part $(a)$, it is true that $(A - I)^{1000} = S (\Lambda - I)^{1000} S^{-1}$. You can justify this by using the fact that $A - I = S( \Lambda - I) S^{-1}$. Hopefully this should allow you to immediately calculate the answer for part $(a)$.

You should try something similar for the other parts.

Comment: ~the problem for me is the $\Lambda$ matrix.  I calculated $\mathcal f(\lambda)$ and get a matrix that is supposed to represent the diagonal in the $\Lambda$ matrix.  So then I have two matrices inside a matrix....

Comment: If $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are $\lambda_i$, then $f(\Lambda)$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are $f(\lambda_i)$.

Comment: ~ exactly.  So when I calculate $\Lambda$ for part a) I get $(\lambda_1-I)^{4000}$ for the 1,1 entry in $\Lambda$ and $(\lambda_2-I)^{4000}$ for the 2,2 entry in $\Lambda$.  They are matrices.  Or should I replace A with $\Lambda-I$ and then calculate $\mathcal S\Lambda\mathcal S^-1$?

Comment: Look at what I've written above. You should be calculating $(\Lambda - I)^{1000}$. So your diagonal matrix is $\Lambda - I$.

Comment: ~ that's what I did.  That makes more sense to me.  For part c) can I just replace $\mathcal A$ with $\mathcal S\Lambda\mathcal S^{-1}$ and then calculate the entire function using that $\mathcal A$? Or would you just use the original $\mathcal A$ ?

Comment: Yes, you replace $A$ with $\Lambda$ by moving $S$ and $S^{-1}$ to the outside.

Comment: ~ Thank you for your time!  You've been very helpful and patient.  :)